# Passing callback as function argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have a hard time with callback and couldn't figure out if this is actually the right way to pass a callback function as an argument. Please help me out. Below is my code snippet

**Service module**

```
jwt.signToken({userName: success.data.username, userId: success.data.userId}, secret, expiresIn, (error, token) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log('::::::::::Error generating token::::::::');
        console.log(error);
        next(returnError({message: 'Internal Server Error', status: 500}));
        } else {
            sendSuccessResponse({data: {token: token, user: {userName: success.data.username, userId: success.data.userId},status: 200}}, response);
        }
});
```

**Auth module**

```
const signToken = (payload, secret, expireIn, callback) => {
    jwt.sign(payload, secret, {expiresIn: expireIn}, (error, token) => callback(error, token));
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: yup, that there be a callback.

Comment: @KevinB I didnt get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What you have is in fact an example of a callback being used within javascript. in other words..... "Yes"

Comment: Or, in yet different words, you're already doing it correctly... What do you need from us?

Comment: I'm a newbie in node and JS, so wanted to know if the way I'm implementing is correct. BTW thank you very much for your response.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Actually I have an issue here. the below part

(error, token) => callback(error, token)

from **Auth module** is not invoking the implementation provided in the **service module**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the issue you are having, including the error you are getting or what is happening that you are not expecting.

Comment: the below part


const signToken = (payload, secret, expireIn, callback) => {
    jwt.sign(payload, secret, {expiresIn: expireIn}, (error, token) => callback(error, token));
};


Should give me token back to my **service module** and I need to send the same in JSON response from my POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to successfully execute the code..Reiterating look at the code how I'm handling the callback in **service** layer

```
jwt.signToken({userName: success.data.username, userId: success.data.userId}, secret, expiresIn, function(error, token) {
    if(error) {
        next(returnError({message: 'Internal Server Error', status: 500}));
        } else {
            sendSuccessResponse({
                data: {
                token: `${token}`,
                user: {
                    userName: success.data.username,
                    userId: success.data.userId
                }
            },
            status: 200
        },response);
    }
});
```

And my **jwt module** is

```
const signToken = (payload, secret, expireIn, callback) => {
    jwt.sign(payload, secret, {expiresIn: expireIn}, (error, token) => callback(error, token));
};
```

This can be a simple demonstration of passing callback implementation (done in one module) to another function (in another module) as a parameter.